# Can I host both a webservice and a WCF service on the same website in IIS?

Tags: wcf, wcf-hosting

I currently have a website where I'm hosting a webservice with several web methods, I need to add some new web methods, but I want to move to the WCF services model rather than continue with asmx.  I want to be able to host the WCF service in the same IIS 6 website as the asmx is - is this possible and if so are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could host the WCF service in a virtual directory under the one holding the ASMX service. You will have to make the new virtual directory be an application, so it can have its own bin folder.

BTW, you distinguish "web services" from "WCF services". This is a false distinction. WCF is the replacement for the legacy ASMX technology, and can do both plain SOAP like ASMX services, or just about anything else.

Comment: ok makes sense.  Any issues with converting the existing asmx to wcf services from the perspective of the client?  I would like to make move forward with WCF for everything, but don't want to have to change anything on the clients that are currently using these services.

Comment: @Tone: the clients will notice nothing but the change of URL.